# List all files in a directory given a regular expression / a set of extensions (Matlab)

Tags: file, matlab

I have a regular expression defining the filenames of interest. What is the best way to list all files in a directory that match this condition?

My attempt at this is:

```
f = dir(DIR);
f = {f([f.isdir] == 0).name};
result = f(~cellfun(@isempty, regexpi(f, '.*(avi|mp4)')));
```

However, I wonder if there is a faster and/or cleaner solution to this?

Is is possible to simplify it if instead of a regular expression I have only a list of possible file extensions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fundamentally your approach is what I would go for. However, your lines of code can be **simplified** to (directories are lost in the regex and empty cells in the final concatenation):

```
f = dir('C:\directory');
f = regexpi({f.name},'.*txt|.*pdf','match');
f = [f{:}];
```

Also, note that the function `dir()` accepts **wildcards** (`*`) but not multiple extensions:

```
dir('C:\directory\*.avi')
```

This means you can retrieve immediately only those files that match an extension, however you have to **loop** for the number of extensions:

```
d   = 'C:\users\oleg\desktop';
ext = {'*.txt','*.pdf'};
f   = [];
for e = 1:numel(ext)
    f = [f; dir(fullfile(d,ext{e}))];
end
```

### Alternative (not recommended)

```
ext = {'*.txt','*.pdf'};
str = ['!dir ' sprintf('%s ',ext{:}) '/B'];
textscan(evalc(str),'%s','Delimiter','')
```

where `str` is `!dir *.txt *.pdf /B` and `evalc()` captures the evaluation of the string and `textscan()` parses it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Btw, why are the empty cells lost during the final concatenation? Could you point me to where this is documented?

Comment: You are concatenating the elements in `{[],{'something'}}` where the empty cell has size is 0x0.

Comment: Some documentation can be found in [empty matrices, scalars and vectors](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/empty-matrices-scalars-and-vectors.html) which can be combined with implicit conversion among types found in [valid combinations of unlike classes](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/valid-combinations-of-unlike-classes.html) (check also links there).

Comment: Alright, thanks. As to this line: `f = {f([f.isdir] == 0).name};`, I'd still leave it there as there could be (theoretically) some directories ending e.g. in ".pdf".

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a cell array with possible extensions, e.g., `exts = {'avi','mp4'}`. Then you can do the following

```
f = cellfun( @(x) dir( fullfile( DIR, ['*.',x] ) ), exts, 'UniformOuput', false ); 
result = [f{:}];
```

Answer (score 0):

My loop variation:

```
ext = [".doc",".docx",".rtf"];
f = [];
for e = ext
    f = [f;dir(char(strcat('**/*',e)))];
end
f = f([f.isdir] == 0);
```