# Launch a Matlab script based on a file extension

Tags: matlab

Hi I'm trying to create a matlab script in a way that it reads all files in a directory and launches a different command for every file extension.
I have:

```
teqc1.azi
teqc1.ele
teqc1.sn1
teqc2.azi
teqc****
```

what i need is that script reads the files and launches recursively the command:

```
`teqc1.azi -> plot_compact_2(teqc1.azi)`
`teqc1.ele -> plot_compact_2(teqc1.ele)`
`teqc1.sn1 -> plot_compact_2(teqc1.sn1)`
`teqc****  -> plot_compact_2(teqc****)`
```

This is what I've come up to right now:

```
function plot_teqc


 d=dir('*'); % <- retrieve all names: file(s) and folder(s)
     d=d(~[d.isdir]); % <- keep file name(s), only
     d={d.name}.'; % <- file name(s)
     nf=name(d);
for i=1:nf

    plot_compact_2(d,'gps');
% type(d{i});
end
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far? What have you tried? If you want help then you need to first show that you have made an effort. If all you need is someone to write the code for you based on criteria, there are freelancers that you can hire...

Comment: You're right, that was stupid. I've added my "effort" :)

Comment: First, you say you want to run "a different command for every file extension", but then you always run the same one - `plot_compact_2`. Can you make it clearer?

Comment: ok i've fixed the plot_compact_2 function so to manage the different extensions, what i need now is just a recursive command that calls for every file in the directory the plot_compact_2 function. sorry for the caos I'm just beginning now to learn matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you'll need the [dir](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) function to list the folder contents and the [fileparts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) function to get the extensions.

You can also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751842/list-all-files-in-a-directory-given-a-regular-expression-a-set-of-extensions) to see how to get a list of all files in a directory that match a certain mask.

So:

```
% get folder contents
filelist = dir('/path/to/directory'); 
% keep only files, subdirectories will be removed
filelist = {filelist([filelist.isdir] == 0).name};

% loop through files
for i=1:numel(filelist)
    % call your function, give the full file path as parameter
   plot_compact_2(fullfile('/path/to/directory', filelist{i}));
end
```