# MATLAB dir command not working properly

Tags: matlab

I have a folder containing 9 .htk files. I need to use "dir", and then "readhtk" in a loop to import them to MATLAB, but DIR appears to give 10 files instead of 9! here is my code:

```
htkfiles = dir('/Users/Desktop/Acsegment/mfcdir/*.htk');
nhtkfiles = length(htkfiles); % 10!!! It should be 9 tough!
data = cell(nhtkfiles,2);
for k = 1:nhtkfiles
    b(k,1) = strcat({'/Users/Desktop/Acsegment/mfcdir/'},{htkfiles(k,1).name});
    eval(['data{k,1} = readhtk(b{k,1});']);
end
```

When looking at the filenames in htkfiles, I have them like this:

```
  htkfiles(1,1).name = '.htk'
  htkfiles(2,1).name = 'fadg0_si1279.htk'
  htkfiles(3,1).name = 'fadg0_si1909.htk'
  htkfiles(4,1).name = 'fadg0_si649.htk'
  htkfiles(5,1).name = 'fadg0_sx109.htk'
  htkfiles(6,1).name = 'fadg0_sx19.htk'
  htkfiles(7,1).name = 'fadg0_sx199.htk'
  htkfiles(8,1).name = 'fadg0_sx289.htk'
  htkfiles(9,1).name = 'fadg0_sx379.htk'
  htkfiles(10,1).name = 'faks0_si943.htk'
```

Comparing to what I see in that folder, the first file is not supposed to be there! Anyone got any ideas why Im getting one extra file?

Comment: Are you working on Linux? In Linux, files whose name starts with `.` are hidden files

Comment: Oh I didn't know about that, so how can I fix it to work properly?

Comment: Filter out names that start with `.`

Comment: In this particular case, just changing your `dir` to `f*.htk` should work. (Also, that `eval` is not needed).

Comment: nkjt: I see your point, but I actually have many files (1344 files),and not all of them start with f.  but how I can filter out the files starting with '.'?

Comment: @KianStar one common solution is to use `regexp` on the return from `dir`. While the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751842/list-all-files-in-a-directory-given-a-regular-expression-a-set-of-extensions) is for matching specific files, the approach should be the same for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: the `dir` command actually works properly, there just happens to be a hidden file.

These files starting with a dot could be removed from your list like so:

```
d=dir;
d(strncmp({d.name},'.',1))=[];
```

Comment: A great help! Thanks a lot ! :)