# Changing all images in a specific folder to type jpeg in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, format

I need to change (and not to keep the old) all the images in a specific folder (and subfolders) to format of type jpeg and save all of the images in one folder.
I'm new to Matlab. What I tried:

```
function convertImages(Folder,ImgType)
Imgs = dir(fullfile(Folder,ImgType));
for i=1:numel(Imgs)
    oldFilename = fullfile(Folder, Imgs(i).name);
    [~,name,~] = fileparts(Imgs(i).name);
    newFilename = fullfile(Folder, strcat(name, '.jpg'));
    imwrite(imread(oldFilename), newFilename);
end
end
```

When I try to run convertImages('images','png'), Imgs is empty - but I have in the folder 6 files and two of them are png.

When I try to run convertImages('images','*') Imgs loads 8 files, two of them are '.'  and '..'  ,  two files I cannot see and it crashes matlab.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tired `convertImages('images','*.png')`?

Comment: that was it .. thanks! silly mistake. do you want to post an answer?

Comment: oh . And I have many different file formats , How can I specify more then one format? I mean not only png but also gif , tiff  and other

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751842/list-all-files-in-a-directory-given-a-regular-expression-a-set-of-extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the '.' and '..' stand for the current and parent directories.
Now in order to support multiple types what I would do is make `ImgType` a cell array with all possible types. For example:

```
ImgType = {'.png','gif'};
```

and use

```
Imgs = dir(fullfile(Folder,'*'));
```

In order to avoid the first 2 entries of `Imgs` just start the loop from 3 instead of 1. Finally in order to check the file type you can do:

```
[~,name,ext] = fileparts(Imgs(i).name);
if any(cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x,ext), ImgType))
...
end
```